# Is there a shortcut on the Game Over screen to resume from the last save?

Tags: the-witcher-2

Clearly, I'm dying quite frequently, and the mouse controls in this game aren't the best.

Is there a shortcut on the keyboard that chooses the "Yes" option for you so you can go back to get murdered in a new way?

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one!

Comment: On a side note, are you experiencing mouse lag in the menus and none in game, too? VSync is on, btw.

Comment: @Bora Absolutely.  The mouse is really unwieldy and imprecise in the menus, but the game responds beautifully otherwise.

Comment: ditto here.

Comment: in the Witcher 2/Config/User.ini file, you can add (or change) the following: "MouseSmoothness=0" and "Smoothness=0".  This, along with turning vsync on, solved my mouse lag issues in the menus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the Enter key? It works for me.

Now if only there were a way to speed up the fade out, fade in effect for that screen...